How to list GCP Artifact Image details in my CLI
I have used this code and got 2 values in column which are (Latest Image & Size) but now i want all the details(image Created/updated/built, digest etc....) of this particular image to be printed in CSV.Can anyone let me know what are the changes to be done in the below script.
Script Used:
echo "REPO,SIZE" > repository-size-report.csv
for REPO in $(gcloud container images list --repository eu.gcr.io/comerge-comerge01-171833 --format="tableno-heading") ; do
for TAGS in $(gcloud container images list-tags $REPO --format="tableno-heading"); do
TAG=$(echo $TAGS | cut -d, -f1)
SUM=0
    for SIZE in $(gcloud container images describe $REPO:$TAG --log-http 2>&1 | grep size | grep -o '[0-9][0-9]*') ; do
      SUM=$((SUM + SIZE))
    done
    HSUM=$(echo $SUM | numfmt --to iec --format "%8f")
    echo "$REPO:$TAG,$HSUM"
    echo "$REPO:$TAG,$HSUM" >> repository-size-report.csv

done

done
